# How can I implement an Activity Indicator for a Carousel in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to incorporate an ActivityIndicator before launching a Carousel page; so that when the Carousel page is heavy on content; the user will know that the app is still loading / hasn't hung.

To figure this out, I'm working from this sample which uses a Carousel page:
https://github.com/chrisriesgo/xamarin-forms-carouselview

My main approach was trying to modify the button to create an ActivityIndicator within the button command:

## Original Sample from "SwitcherPage.cs"

```
var none = new Button {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Text = "No pager indicator",
            Command = new Command((obj) => Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage(CarouselLayout.IndicatorStyleEnum.None)))
        };
```

## My Attempt

```
var indicator = new ActivityIndicator ();

        var none = new Button {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Text = "No pager indicator",
            Command = new Command(
                indicator.IsRunning,
                indicator.IsVisible,
                Task.Delay(2500), // to simulate a long loading time
                (obj) => Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage(CarouselLayout.IndicatorStyleEnum.None)))
        };
```

## What I know so far

Intellisense is already telling me that's wrong; I can't define it in the command that way. But hopefully that illustrates what I'm trying to do; essentially trigger an activity indicator while waiting for the page to load.

I've looked for general resources on the ActivityIndicator, but the problem is I haven't found any that I can figure out how to convert that to something that will activate after the button is pressed while waiting for the Carousel page to load.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator/
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34502/xamarin-forms-activity-indicator
[Xamarin.Forms - How to overlay an ActivityIndicator in the middle of a StackLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885525/xamarin-forms-how-to-overlay-an-activityindicator-in-the-middle-of-a-stacklayo)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but:

```
    var indicator = new ActivityIndicator ();

    var none = new Button {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Text = "No pager indicator",
        Command = new Command(async() => {
            indicator.IsRunning = true;
            indicator.IsVisible = true;
            await Task.Delay(2500);
            indicator.IsRunning = false;
            indicator.IsVisible = false;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage(CarouselLayout.IndicatorStyleEnum.None));
        })
    };
```

But It would be a lot cleaner to set appropriate bindings to you ViewModel properties and do things from there.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution, Using Device.StartTimer

```
var indicator = new ActivityIndicator ();

var none = new Button {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    Text = "No pager indicator",
    Command = new Command(() => {
        indicator.IsRunning = true;
        indicator.IsVisible = true;
        Device.StartTimer(Timespan.FromSeconds(2.5),()=>
        {
            indicator.IsRunning = false;
            indicator.IsVisible = false;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage(CarouselLayout.IndicatorStyleEnum.None));
            return false;
        });
    });

};
```